# Align scroll down arrow to the bottom center of a full-screen div in WPBakery Visual Composer

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

I have a series of full-screen divs in Visual Composer and I want an arrow at the bottom of each one indicating to users they should scroll for more content. I tried absolute positioning on the divs containing the icon with no luck. All I've done is move the icon a few pixels to th

```
<section class="l-section wpb_row height_full valign_center width_full with_img" id="home">
<div class="l-section-img loaded" data-img-width="1920" data-img-height="809">
</div>

<div class="l-section-h i-cf">
<div class="g-cols vc_row type_default valign_top">
<div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column vc_column_container">
<div class="vc_column-inner">
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
<div class="w-image align_center" id="mainlogo">
<div class="w-image-h"><img src="logo.png" class="attachment-full size-full">
</div>
</div>


<div class="ult-just-icon-wrapper">
<div class="align-icon" style="text-align:center;">

<a class="aio-tooltip" href="#whatis">
<div class="aio-icon none " style="display:inline-block;">

<i class="Defaults-chevron-down"></i>

</div>
</a>

</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</section>
```

Existing CSS:

```
.aio-icon.none {
    display: inline-block;
}
.aio-tooltip {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.vc_column-inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.wpb_column {
    position: relative;
}
.vc_column_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.vc_row {
    position: relative;
}
.l-section-h {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The icon itself is the **Defaults-chevron-down**.

Do you have an idea how to position that icon properly?

Comment: position relative on the parent `div` and `position:absolute` on the icon  and position it where you want  , did you try that and it didn't work ? Please share the CSS you tried

Comment: thanks for trying to help. i did try position:relative and absolute on all parent/child divs in the page, without luck. maybe something in the existing css stands in the way? i've pasted the existing css that WPBakery generates.

Comment: `.wpb_row { position: relative } .ult-just-icon-wrapper { position: absolute; bottom:0; margin:0 auto; } ` try this or something along these lines. Should work.

Comment: it doesn't work, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled a little with this. But there is a rather quick and dirty fix for this:

**Just put another row below the full height row. Place your icon there and give this element a top margin of i.e. -200px.**

For some strange reason the rather logical approach to put the icon in the full height row itself and to position it absolute to the bottom is not properly supported by the source generated from WPB.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue this week. The way I resolved it was added the icon in that row/section (in my case a single image element with a custom link to a .svg) and added a class to it.

The CSS for the class was then:

```
position:absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
margin-top:-30px;
```

(I added a negative margin top as I noticed the icon was cutting of a little on my Google Pixel phone with the fixed bottom bar so that pulled it up a little.)